# Failing to execute dynamic query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, moodle

I am trying to fetch data from a database in Moodle with a dynamic query but I tell me that there is an error in the reading of the database:

```
$parts = $_POST['make'];
$arr = explode(':', $parts);

$sql = "SELECT mdl_block_report_bbb_meeting.id,
          mdl_block_report_bbb_meeting.name, 
          mdl_block_report_bbb_meeting.create_time, 
          mdl_block_report_bbb_meeting.end_time,
          mdl_block_report_bbb_user_events.id as ueid,
          mdl_block_report_bbb_user_events.name as uename, 
          mdl_block_report_bbb_user_events.join_time, 
          mdl_block_report_bbb_user_events.left_time
        FROM mdl_block_report_bbb_meeting 
        JOIN mdl_block_report_bbb_user_events
          ON mdl_block_report_bbb_meeting.id =
             mdl_block_report_bbb_user_events.meeting_id
        WHERE uename LIKE '%$arr%'";
    
$result = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Never ever use `$_POST` directly, it allows SQL injection.

Use `optional_param` or `required_param` to clean the data.

```
$parts = required_param('make', PARAM_TEXT);
$arr = explode(':', $parts);
```

`$arr` now contains an array which you can't use with a `LIKE`.

You probably want to use this

```
list($where, $params) = $DB->get_in_or_equal($arr, SQL_PARAMS_NAMED, 'uename');
```

Use aliases in your SQL to make it easier to read, and type.

Also don't use "mdl", the table prefix is a setting that can be changed, so use { } brackets around the table name.

```
$sql = "SELECT m.id,
      m.name, 
      m.create_time, 
      m.end_time,
      ue.id as ueid,
      ue.name as uename, 
      ue.join_time, 
      ue.left_time
    FROM {block_report_bbb_meeting} m
    JOIN {block_report_bbb_user_events} ue ON ue.meeting_id = m.id   
    WHERE ue.name {$where}";

// Always pass the values as params, again to avoid injection.
$result = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, $params);
```